# Foundation/Bootstrap dropdowns not working on Chrome when used with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I'm using *HTML5 Boilerplate* for a zurb foundation *v5.4.6* project. Everything works fine except the dropdown navigation bar links *(see attached pics)* when I use Modernizr *v2.8.3*. The links are supposed to reveal on **hover**. But with Modernizr enabled this is how it behaves on these browsers:

- **Chrome** *v38.0.2125.104*: Doesn't reveal even on click
- **Firefox** *v31.0*: Reveals on click
- **IE** *v11.0*: Reveals on click

So in none of these is the normal 'reveal on hover' behaviour is observed. Please help me whats going on.
[image: With Modernizr]

[image: Without Modernizr]

The head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>testapp</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/foundation/css/normalize.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css"> 
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
<script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The body:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
<nav class="top-bar">
  <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#" title="Home">Guitarbaba.in</a>
          </h1>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="left">
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#" title="">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="">Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#" title="">Item 3</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#" title="">Sub Item 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="">Sub Item 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="">Sub Item 3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="">Sub Item 4</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="">Sub Item 5</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </section>
</nav>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
<script>
  (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
  function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
  e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
  e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
  r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
  ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X');ga('send','pageview');
</script>

    <!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. What seems to fix for me (Linux, chromium) is adding `data-topbar` after the "top-bar" class of the nav, like so:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
```

For good examples, see: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html